# How To Get Every Alternate Object In Array In JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, local-storage

I wanted to know how can we get every alternate object in a array. For EG -

```
arr = ["foo","bar","foo1","bar1"]
```

I Need The values -

```
fir_alt = ["foo","foo1"]
sec_alt = ["bar","bar1"]
```

If This Helps This Is My Intention -

I am trying to link localstorage and firestore using the js-sdk.. Data is in array and have to take the array to store it back in localstorage.fir_alt would be the keys and sec_alt would be values. So I Can Make it Much More Multi-Device..

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the filter function to filter out even and odd index's.

```js
arr = ["foo","bar","foo1","bar1"]

fir_alt = arr.filter((element, index) => index % 2 == 0);
sec_alt = arr.filter((element, index) => index % 2 == 1);

console.log('fir_alt', fir_alt)
console.log('sec_alt', sec_alt)
```

Comment: Thanks A Lot Jacob.. Really Helped. Appreciate it A Lot As This Is My First Question On StackOverflow

Comment: The problem with above solution is you will loop over original array twice, solution given by @VL93 seems right.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use an index variable and a loop(for/next or your fav).  Examine the index on each iteration of the loop, and determine if the index is odd or even(or 0), then take the appropriate action to capture the desired values.

Answer (score 1):

If I know what you mean... We can be reasoned with odd and even index.
In this way:

```
let arr = ["foo","bar","foo1", "bar1"],
    fir_alt = [],
    sec_alt = [];

for (let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if ((i+2)%2==0) {
        sec_alt.push(arr[i]);
    }
    else {
        fir_alt.push(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Really Nice VL93.. But This Is A Very Long And Congested Code... Thanks For The Reply Though!

Comment: Not very long or even congested. Try to understand it better and why it is better than the marked correct answer.

Comment: @pritam, In Jacob's answer the code is much more simpler and as you stated in the comment section...Yes it will be true.. Still I prefer Jacob's answer... No offence Just my Opinion.. Thanks For Suggestion Though!

Comment: Sure, you could use simpler solutions but there'll be a time when you would have to think about the performance of your algorithm.